# Suppose $f, g : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ are bounded functions which disagree on a finite set. I want to show 1) $U(f) = U(g)$ and 2) $L(f) = L(g)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f, g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are bounded functions which disagree on a finite set.  I want to show 1)  $U(f) = U(g)$ and 2) $L(f) = L(g)$.

Comment: What are $U$ and $L$? Maybe $\ess\sup$ and $\ess\inf$?

Comment: You can try something a bit niftier. First, think about the case where they disagree at exactly one point; then, use interval additivity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assumeing $ U $ and $ L $ are the upper and lower Darboux sums respectively since that's a fairly standard notation. I don't think you need to use induction. If we have $ n $ many points where $ f $ and $ g $ differ, the idea is to take a partition that isolates these points where they are not equal. We'll do the upper sum for now and the lower sum should be similar.

We fix $ \varepsilon>0 $, and we have that $ f $ and $ g $ are not equal only on the points $ D=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} $. Let $ M = \max_{i\in [n]}\{|f(x_i)-f(g_i)|\} $.

We take a partition $ P $ such that $ U_{f,P} < U_f + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} $ and $ U_{g,P} < U_g + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} $. This is possible since $ U_f $ is just the infimum of $ \{U_{f,P}\} $ over all partitions $ P $.

We then take another partition $ P_2 $  $$ a = y_0 < y_1<\ldots < y_m = b $$ such that for each $ x_i $, we have for some $ k\in \{0,\ldots,m-1\} $ that $ x_i\in (y_{k},y_{k+1}) $ and if $ i\neq j $ then $ x_i $ and $ x_j $ are in different parts of the partition, and the size of the interval in the partition that contain each $ x_i $ is less than $ \frac{\varepsilon}{8M\cdot n} $

We let $ Q $ be a refinement of $ P $ and $ P_2 $. It's an easy exercise to show that for any function $ h $, that $ U_{h,Q} \leq \min\{U_{h,P},U_{h,P_2}\} $. So, we have that 
$$ U_{f,Q} < U_f + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \quad U_{g,Q} < U_g + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} $$
So, we see that $$ \tag{1}\label{eq:1}|U_{f,Q} - U_{g,Q}| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}2|f(x_i) - g(x_i)|\cdot L_i $$ where $ L_i $ is the size of the partition piece of $ Q $ that contains $ x_i $ (and we have a 2 in case that $ x_i $ happens to lie on points defining the partition, in which it is counted at most twice). 
But, we observe that $ L_i $ is at most the size of the original interval in partition $ P_2 $ that contains the $ x_i $, so its length is at most $ \frac{\varepsilon}{8M\cdot n} $. Thus, we have that $$ \ref{eq:1} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2M\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{8M\cdot n} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$ Thus, we see that $$ U_f - U_G < \varepsilon $$ (by triangle inequality), and $ \varepsilon $ was arbitrary.
The proof for the lower darboux sum is similar, so I'll leave it as an exercise.